# Date filter for line chart

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, syncfusion

I'm very new to React, so I apologize if my question is unclear. I have a local array of data whereby I used Syncfusion to make a line chart. For the next step, I want to create a dateRange where I can filter the date, and the chart accordingly updates based on that date range. I'm looking for how it can be done.

I've tried to create a DateRangePickerComponent using Syncfusion and a Line chart of the array. However, I'm unsure how to combine them to update the chart based on the selected date.

This is the DateRangePicker component.

```
 import {
  // CalendarComponent,
  DateRangePickerComponent,
  // PresetsDirective,
  // PresetDirective,
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-calendars";

import { ButtonComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-buttons";

import moment from "moment";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Line from "./Line";

const Calendar = () => {
  // const dateValue = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 20);
  // const startDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 6);
  // const endDate = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), 31);

  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
    start: moment().subtract(12, "hours").format(), //.format('DD/MMM/YYYY'),
    end: moment().add(24, "hours").format(), //.format('DD/MMM/YYYY')
  });

  const dateComponent = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(dateRange);
  }, [dateRange]);

  function getDateRange(range) {
    // console.log(range.startDate)
    // console.log(moment().toDate())
    setDateRange({ start: range.startDate, end: range.endDate });
  }

  var onClickRefresh = (e) => {
    dateComponent.current.value = [
      moment().subtract(12, "hours").toDate(),
      moment().add(24, "hours").toDate(),
    ];
  };

  return (
    // <CalendarComponent
    //   id='calendar'
    //   value={dateValue}
    //   min={startDate}
    //   max={endDate}
    //   height='650px'
    //   isMultiSelection={true}
    //   start='Decade'
    //   depth='Month'
    // >

    <DateRangePickerComponent
      id='daterangepicker'
      cssClass='monitor-dateRangePicker'
      startDate={dateRange.start}
      endDate={dateRange.end}
      placeholder='Select a range'
      format='dd-MM-yyyy'
      ref={dateComponent}
      change={(args) => {
        getDateRange(args);
      }}
      showClearButton={false}
      minDays={1}
      maxDays={7}
      max={moment().format()}
    >
      <div className='control-pane'>
        <div className='control-section'>
          <div className='daterangepicker-control-section'>
            <Line dateRange={dateRange} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ButtonComponent
        cssClass='monitor e-outline'
        iconCss='e-icons e-refresh'
        onClick={onClickRefresh}
      >
        Reset
      </ButtonComponent>
    </DateRangePickerComponent>
    // </CalendarComponent>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

And this is the Line component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import data from "./data";

import {
  Category,
  ChartComponent,
  DataLabel,
  DateTime,
  Inject,
  LineSeries,
  SeriesCollectionDirective,
  SeriesDirective,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "@syncfusion/ej2-react-charts";

const Line = (props) => {
  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState();

  const fetchData = () => {
    if (data.length) {
      console.log(data);

 // const start = new Date().getTime();
  // const end = new Date();
  // end.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  // end.getTime();

  // return data.filter((data) => {
  //   let date = new Date(data.created_at).getTime();
  //   return date >= start && date <= end;
  // });
    }
    setChartData(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    console.log(props.dateRange);
  }, [props.dateRange, chartData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <ChartComponent
        id='Charts'
        title='AAPL'
        primaryXAxis={{ valueType: "Category", title: "Time" }}
        primaryYAxis={{ title: "High" }}
        chartArea={{ border: { width: 0 } }}
        tooltip={{ enable: true }}
        legendSettings={{ background: "white" }}
      >
        <Inject services={[DataLabel, DateTime, Tooltip, LineSeries, Category, Legend]} />
        <SeriesCollectionDirective>
          <SeriesDirective
            type='Line'
            dataSource={data}
            xName='dateTime'
            yName='open'
            name='Open'
            width={2}
            marker={{ visible: true, width: 7, height: 7, shape: "Circle", isFilled: true }}
          />
          <SeriesDirective
            type='Line'
            dataSource={data}
            xName='dateTime'
            yName='high'
            name='High'
            width={2}
            marker={{ visible: true, width: 7, height: 7, shape: "Triangle", isFilled: true }}
          />
        </SeriesCollectionDirective>
      </ChartComponent>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Line;
```

And lastly, this is the local dataset:

```
const data = [
  { dateTime: "2023-01-27 20:00:00", open: 145.98, high: 150.98 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-27 16:00:00", open: 147.95, high: 152.48 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-27 12:00:00", open: 152.94, high: 151.11 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-27 08:00:00", open: 150.9399, high: 155.69 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-27 04:00:00", open: 148.93, high: 148.93 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-27 00:00:00", open: 151.87, high: 151.99 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-26 20:00:00", open: 148.88, high: 152.43 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-26 16:00:00", open: 151.87, high: 153.33 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-26 12:00:00", open: 154.88, high: 160.03 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-26 08:00:00", open: 148.93, high: 149.93 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-26 04:00:00", open: 154.88, high: 155.69 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-26 00:00:00", open: 149.9, high: 153.79 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-25 20:00:00", open: 154.89, high: 152.17 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-25 16:00:00", open: 150.86, high: 153.38 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-25 12:00:00", open: 151.86, high: 155.56 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-25 08:00:00", open: 145.89, high: 147.77 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-25 04:00:00", open: 146.89, high: 148.88 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-25 00:00:00", open: 150.9, high: 152.22 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-24 20:00:00", open: 154.86, high: 159.93 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-24 16:00:00", open: 146.86, high: 153.69 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-24 12:00:00", open: 154.89, high: 158.29 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-24 08:00:00", open: 152.89, high: 155.81 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-24 04:00:00", open: 146.86, high: 148.69 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-24 00:00:00", open: 151.88, high: 152.19 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-23 20:00:00", open: 152.86, high: 152.86 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-23 16:00:00", open: 152.8594, high: 152.95 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-23 12:00:00", open: 146.86, high: 147.79 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-23 08:00:00", open: 149.88, high: 150.69 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-23 04:00:00", open: 151.8605, high: 155.54 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-23 00:00:00", open: 151.95, high: 154.44 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-22 20:00:00", open: 152.93, high: 154.57 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-22 16:00:00", open: 151.89, high: 152.11 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-22 12:00:00", open: 146.91, high: 148.5 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-22 08:00:00", open: 150.93, high: 151.93 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-22 04:00:00", open: 152.93, high: 161.13 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-22 00:00:00", open: 146.96, high: 162.27 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-21 20:00:00", open: 149.9977, high: 156.98 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-21 16:00:00", open: 150.99, high: 154.75 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-21 12:00:00", open: 153.98, high: 159.71 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-21 08:00:00", open: 146, high: 147.97 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-21 04:00:00", open: 145.97, high: 147 },

  { dateTime: "2023-01-21 00:00:00", open: 153.96, high: 155.69 },
];

export default data;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a react application to change the data based on the dateRangepicker component value. Please find the below stackblitz link for your reference.

Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-a4vjoi-fwaeer?file=index.js

If the selected range has data, then the chart gets rendered based on the selected range.

Find the screenshot here:
[image: ChartWithRangeValue]